# How to use the values of a variable belonging to a class in another class?

Tags: c++

I have this code everything is separated by .h file and. cpp: Fitness.h

```
class Fitness
{
private:

   // Professor's ID
   float _fit;

public:

    // Inicia los datos del profesor
    Fitness(float fit);


    // Devuelve professor's ID
    inline float GetFit() const { return _fit; }

};
```

Fitness.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Fitness.h"

// Inicializa los datos del fit este es el archivo cpp 
Fitness::Fitness(float fit) : _fit(fit) { }
```

and the part where I use it is here in a class called file called configuracion: Configuracion.h

```
class Configuracion
{
public:

    //Lectura del Fitness
    hash_map<float, Fitness*> _fit;

private:
    // Indica que aun no se lee la información
    bool _isEmpty;

public:

    // Inicia datos
    Configuracion() : _isEmpty(true) { }

    // Libera recursos usados
    ~Configuracion();

    // Analiza datos y guarda datos
    void ParseFile(char* fileName);

    ///Fitness////////////////////////////
    inline Fitness* GetFit(float fit)
    {
        hash_map<float, Fitness*>::iterator it = _fit.find(fit);

        return it != _fit.end() ? (*it).second : NULL;
    }

    inline float GetNFit() const
    {
        return (float)_fit.size();
    }

    Fitness* ParseFitness(ifstream& file);

    // Remueve caracteres vacios al principio y fin de la cadena
    string& TrimString(string& str);
};
```

Configuracion.cpp

```
Configuracion::~Configuracion()
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (hash_map<float, Fitness*>::iterator it = _fit.begin(); it != _fit.end();      it++)
        delete (*it).second;
}

void Configuracion::ParseFile(char* fileName)
{
    // Limpia objetos previamente analizados
    _fit.clear();

    string line;
    while( input.is_open() && !input.eof() )
    {
        // Leer linea por linea hasta que se obtenga el inicio de un nuevo objeto
        getline( input, line );
        TrimString( line );

        // Lee, analiza y guarda el tipo de objeto 
        if (line.compare("#fit") == 0)
        {
            Fitness* f = ParseFitness(input);

            if (f)
                _fit.insert(pair<float, Fitness*>(f->GetFit(), f));

        }//////////////////cambiar variable o modificar    
    }

    input.close();
    _isEmpty = false;
```

To the use the value of the variable in another file within another class:

```
float f1 = 0.000000;
//f1 = Configuracion::GetInstance().GetFit();

f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);

//Horario * f1= &Configuracion::_fit;
if (best->GetFitness() >= 0.45000000)
{
    // ...
}
```

In this line I have an error :

```
f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);
```

This is the error:

```
Error    2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'stdext::hash_map<float,Fitness *,stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,std::less<_Kty>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> Configuracion::* ' to 'float'
```

Comment: You need to properly indent your code. Without proper, logical indentation, it is hard to follow.

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `Configuracion::_fit` is not a `float` type. Besides, it's not even a static member

Comment: `Fitness::_fit` is a `float`.  `Configuracion::_fit` is a `stdext::hash_map<float,Fitness *,stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,std::less<_Kty>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>`, or a `stdext::hash_map<float, Fitness*>` for short.  `&Configuracion::_fit` is a pointer-to-member-data for the second type.  I don't think you want to convert a pointer-to-member-data to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are two major problems with this line:

```
f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);
```

First of all, `_fit` is a non-static member of the `Configuracion` class, which means that you can't access it unless you refer to an instance of `Configuracion`. For example:

```
Configuracion myConfiguracion;  // Create instance of Configuracion.

f1  = myConfiguracion._fit;     // Access member variable.
```

Second, `Configuracion::_fit` has the type `hash_map<float, Fitness*>`. You cannot assign a `hash_map` object to a `float` because their types are incompatible. It's difficult to see what you're trying to achieve, so I can't tell you how to fix it. You should re-evaluate the function in question and fix accordingly.